# Cant create xml in C Drive through web application (attempt to perform unauthorized operation)

Tags: c#

I create a c# web application to create XML in C#. It worked and the file shown up when I compound in Visual Studio 2013. When I publish into web and access it through browser, the file doesnt show up. I try catch the error message and the message is **attempt to perform unauthorized operation**.

I tried to add impersonate into web config.
I tried to add IUSR profile into C drive.

But still, I cant create the XML file. Please Help.

```
         using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
         {
             XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
             dom.Load(reader);

             var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
             settings.Indent = true;
             settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;


             var path = string.Format(@"C:\");
             // if directory already exists nothing will happen
             Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
             using (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(@"C:\iLabelWM_" + DN + "_" + System.DateTime.Today.Year + System.DateTime.Today.Month.ToString("d2") + System.DateTime.Today.Day.ToString("d2") + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("d2") + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("d2") + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("d2") + "_" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString("d3") + ".xml", settings))
             {
                 dom.WriteContentTo(writer);
             }
```

Comment: The root of the C drive is restricted - there are most likely some special hoops you'll have to jump through for your web application to write files there.  Is there a reason you want the file in the root of C?

Comment: try with some other drive.see if it works

Comment: I need to write into the C Drive as it is one of the requirement of my project

Answer (score 0):

there is an error you are trying to create a directory with path , that has c:\ as content.

```
var path = string.Format(@"C:\");
             // if directory already exists nothing will happen
             Directory.CreateDirectory(path);  // <-- you can't create directory c:\
```

what you should use is

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

code sample:

```
var path = Request.ApplicationPath;

             using (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(path + DN + "_" + System.DateTime.Today.Year + System.DateTime.Today.Month.ToString("d2") + System.DateTime.Today.Day.ToString("d2") + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("d2") + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("d2") + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("d2") + "_" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString("d3") + ".xml", settings))
             {
                 dom.WriteContentTo(writer);
             }
```